# How do we put bullet points inside the cells of an excel sheet?

Tags: excel

I have tried copying text from Word, but that's cumbersome every time. Hence could someone tell me how I can insert bullet points inside a cell?

Comment: Have you tried googling "bullet points in excel"? One of the first results: https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Insert-bullets-in-a-worksheet-60274daa-8079-4b40-8f69-0652dbadb4ec

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft provides pretty excellent documentation on how to do this (found through a quick Google search, no less!):  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/323567

To create the bullet point symbol, type ALT+0149.

If you want to apply bullet point to an entire column or selection of cells, highlight those cells, look at the top of your screen and make sure you're on "Home", then click Number (Should be between alignment and font) and pick Custom.  There should be an @ symbol in the type box.  Click to the left of it and type ALT-0149 to put the bullet point in and check the example above it to make sure it's how you want it.